# Partial string replace with gsub

Tags: ruby, replace, gsub

I have an array of different image urls where I need to replace "/s_" with "/xl_". Ive tried a number of different ways, but non of them seems to work as I expect them to. Here is my latest version:

```
available_images.each do |img|
    img.gsub(/.*(\/s_).*\.jpg/, "\/xl_")
end
```

available_images is the array holding a number of strings (which of course match the provided regex: .*(/s_).*.jpg ).
Any thoughts on how that can be fixed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `gsub!` (`!` because you do a `each` and not a `map`) with a simple string (instead of a regex) should work:

```
"path/to/s_image.jpg".gsub '/s_', '/xl_'
# => "path/to/xl_image.jpg"
```

**Update**

As pointed out in the comments, the solution might result in unexpected behavior if the path contains multiple occurrences of `'/s_'`.

```
"path/s_thing/s_image.jpg".gsub '/s_', '/xl_'
#=> "path/xl_thing/xl_image.jpg"
          ▲        ▲
```

[Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin) posted a nice, short regex substitution, which works in that case:

```
"path/s_thing/s_image.jpg".sub %r|/s_(?!.*/)|, '/xl_'
#=> "path/s_thing/xl_image.jpg"
          △        ▲
```

It only replaces the last occurrence of `'/s_'`.

Comment: Probably `sub` is more appropriate

Comment: `sub` is probably as wrong as `gsub` is. In the case of multiple occurences of the string '/s_' both may result in unexpected bahavior. Maybe `sub! /(.*)(?:\/s_)(.*\.jpg)/, "#{$1}/xl_#{$2}"` is better (but more complex)

Comment: `sub %r|/s_(?!.*/)|, '/xl_'`